# SQL server insert trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, if-statement, triggers

I'm a novice at SQL server and I have a task to create a trigger that will insert/update a customer's status to 'Blocked' in a payment is overdue.

How could I check to say something like the following within a trigger?

```
if getdate() > dateDue
then update status = 'Blocked'
end if
```

Many thanks for you help in advance

Comment: You can't as triggers don't fire according to times. Better to check the `getdate` vs `duedate` at time of `select`. You can create a non persisted computed column with this logic.

Comment: Saying "You can't" is not true...  You can certainly have a trigger that fires only after dateDue is modified, and then in the trigger body you can update that record's status if dateDue is < the current time.

Comment: @Jim What if the dateDue is set to a week in the future, but then later selected a month in the future?  If the dueDate isn't updated in the interim, the status will be inaccurate if it relies on a trigger firing..

Comment: The question wasn't really clear on passage of time - it just asked how to update with a trigger.  I provided a second answer that's basically to just run a stored procedure from Agent to check / update the statuses of records.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation of Martin's suggestion to create a [non-persisted computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable 
ADD Status AS CASE WHEN DueDate < GETDATE() THEN 'Blocked' ELSE 'Not Blocked' END
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to really test this, so there might be some problems / syntax issues, but here's something that should give you an idea how to go about it.  Basically, your trigger should fire whenever the value of "dateDue" is changed.  It should iterate through the "inserted" values in case more than one record was updated, and for each record in "inserted", if the new "dateDue" value is > the current time, you update that record and set the status to 'Blocked'.

```
CREATE TRIGGER myTriggerName
ON myTable
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
IF UPDATE(dateDue)
BEGIN
  DECLARE @currPk INT
  DECLARE @currDateDue DATETIME
  DECLARE @today DATETIME
  DECLARE inserted_Cursor CURSOR FOR
  SELECT myTableID, dateDue, GETDATE() FROM Inserted

  OPEN inserted_Cursor;
  FETCH NEXT FROM inserted_Cursor INTO @currPk, @currDateDue, @today
  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

    BEGIN
      IF(@currDateDue < @today)
      UPDATE myTable SET status = 'Blocked' WHERE myTableID = @currPk

      FETCH NEXT FROM inserted_Cursor INTO @currPk, @currDateDue, @today
    END;

  CLOSE inserted_Cursor;
  DEALLOCATE inserted_Cursor;
END;
```

Comment: Why do you need a cursor for this? Should be able to implement the exact same logic in a single UPDATE.

Comment: This is superfluous use of a cursor. You could simply use `UPDATE MyTable SET Status = 'Blocked' FROM MyTable t INNER JOIN inserted i ON i.MyTableID = t.MyTableID WHERE i.DueDate < GETDATE()`. This does not handle the passage of time either, this assumes that the only way a payment becomes overdue is by changing the duedate, forgetting the fact that even with no changes at all to the table at some point every row will satisfy the condition `DueDate < GETDATE()`.

Comment: I suppose you could do that too.  I wrote this quickly, just to give an idea of how it could be done.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have this status updated when dueDate becomes < today, as opposed to only updating it when the dueDate for the record is modified, you should schedule a stored procedure via SQL Sever Agent and have it run a simple update to set the statuses for any records where dueDate < today.  You can run this nightly, or every hour, or whatever you need.

If you don't want to run Agent, you could do it with a Windows service that you write code for (more of a pain to set up), or even a batch file that runs from a Windows Task, but obviously Agent is the most convenient way to do this.